# ArrayList Add Element Overriding

Tags: object, arraylist

Im tryin to add the Objects(tempArticle) in ArrayList(Article) but it just adds the last element of it. 
What Im really tryin to do is to keep each Article's Author in a separate row like normalized. 
First I save each author in a temporary ArrayList(temp) then try to set the author of (tempArticle) and add it in List(Article).
It keeps overriding it.
But it just adds the last Last Author in the ArrayList :/ 
Here's My Code.

```
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Author")) {

        //  System.out.println(tempVal);

            if(tempArticle.getAuthor() != null){

                String old=tempArticle.getAuthor();

                x=tempVal;
                temp.add(x);
                Flag=1;

                if(temp.indexOf(old) < 0 ){

                    System.out.println("Old:  "+old);
                    temp.add(old);
                }

            }
            tempArticle.setAuthor(tempVal);
        }
        if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Article")) {
            //add it to the list
            int Count=0;
            if(Flag >= 1 ){
                while(Count <= temp.size() -1){
                    //System.out.println(" Author: ,   "+temp.get(Count)+"  prev: "+tempArticle.getAuthor());
                    tempArticle.setAuthor(temp.get(Count));
                    System.out.println(tempArticle.getAuthor());

                    Article.add(tempArticle);
                    Count++;
                }
                Flag=0;
                temp.clear();
            }
            else{
                Article.add(tempArticle);
            }
        }
```

I tried printing all indexes of temporary array in which im storing all the authors turns out all the authors are there but when I try to do tempArticle.setAuthor() it just stores the last author of that array.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do more clearly? It's a little hard to see exactly what you want here...

Comment: Can you please mention how is tempArticle object defined?

Comment: Im trying to read XML file and insert it in SQL.
If an Article consist more than 1 author then it should insert as a new row 
thats wat im trying to do.

Comment: tempArticle is an object of class Article which consists of all the attributes like author, title, year etc

Comment: I tried printing all indexes of temporary array in which im storing all the authors turns out all the authors are there but when I try to do tempArticle.setAuthor() it just stores the last author of that array.